# How can I get PMD result report as java object from code?

Tags: java, pmd

I'm writing something like PMD wrapper (the goal is to check the java code with PMD, but with certain features), `pmd-core` and `pmd-java` included to my project like external libraries and I'm executing PMD such way:

```
int violations = PMD.doPMD(configuration);
```

`doPMD` returns number of violations found. By configuring `reportFormat` in `PMDConfiguration` we can set output to `System.out` or to file with one of the available report formats (like xml, html, text, etc.), but...

How can I get PMD result (of all source files were processed) report as java object? Perhaps, it is possible to get a `list<>` of all RuleViolations or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `Renderer`.

1. Create a custom implementation of [`net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.Renderer`](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/renderers/Renderer.java)
2. On your `configuration` call  `setReportFormat` passing the fully quallified name of your custom renderer (ie: `"my.organization.package.InMemoryRenderer"`)
3. run the analysis, just as you are doing

During the analysis process, your renderer will be instantiated exactly once, and `renderFileReport(Report)` method will be called for each file's results. The `Report` [has method's to obtain and iterate over violations, config and execution errors](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/4e331aca2328b50da030f82a807fb9e30cab9d2a/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/Report.java#L474-L495).

These are provided as POJOs, as you intend.

You won't have access to the `Renderer` instance, but you can store data in a static member (make sure to keep thread-safety as PMD runs multithreaded analysis!) and provide a static getter.